# Video .mp4 won't show in any browser

Tags: javascript, css, html, video

Im trying to get videos stored on my local drive to play on a webpage im making. I've tried opening the page in in three browsers but it never shows (prefer chrome). I've run the videos (mp4) directly in chrome and they all work. So it's not a support issue. Below I've attached my HTML and JS. There's CSS associated with this but I don't see why that would cause any playback issues. I've been at this for hours, pretty stuck right now. Also, Im using Aptana for development and running it from there.

**Here is the complete code if anyone wants to take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/pGzTR/**

This is the html I've used:

```
<section id="main_section">
    <video id="myMovie" width="320" height="180">
        <source scr="a1/db.mp4"/>
    </video>
    <nav id="video_nav">
        <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" id="playButton">Play</button>
        </div>
        <div id="defaultBar">
            <div id="progressBar"></div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </nav>                        
</section>
```

**scr="a1/db.mp4" This is referencing the folder where the html and video files reside.**

This is the javascript im using for the functionality

```
function doFirst(){
    barSize = 600;
    myMovie = document.getElementById('myMovie');
    playButton = document.getElementById('playButton');
    bar = document.getElementById('defaultBar');
    progressBar = document.getElementById('progressBar');   
    playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
    bar.addEventListener('click', clickBar, false);

}
function playOrPause(){
        if(!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
        myMovie.pause();
        playButton.innerHTML='Play';
        window.clearInterval(updateBar);
    }else{
        myMovie.play();
        playButton.innerHTML='Pause';
        updateBar=setInterval(update, 700)
    }
}
function update(){
    if(!myMovie.ended){
        size = parseInt((myMovie.currentTime*barSize)/myMovie.duration);
        progressBar.style.width = size +'px';
    }else{
        progressBar.style.width='0px';
        playButton.innerHTML='Play';
        window.clearInterval(updateBar);
    }
}
function clickBar(e){
    if(!myMovie.paused && !myMovie.ended){
        mouseX=e.pageX-bar.offsetLeft;
        newTime=mouseX*myMovie.duration/barSize;
        myMovie.currentTime=newTime;
        progressBar.style.width=mouseX+'px';
    }
}

window.addEventListener('load',doFirst,false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure you have `MIME` type added for `.MP4` in `IIS` or whatever service you are using to host the website.

EDIT:

Please ensure that `MP4` file path is correct. That seems as a problem to me in after looking at your screenshot.

Comment: the file isn't hosted anywhere. It's local and im using Aptana as my IDE

Comment: Refer this link to add MIME type in APTANA https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-3984

Comment: Im not really sure what to do with this there's no instructions. Also what's really annoying is that I have another file that's referencing the same video (stored in different folder) and it works fine. So I don't think the problem is Aptana mime types. http://jumpshare.com/v/oI9lmV?b=77Z7id The one on the right works, on the left does not. Really annoying.

Comment: are you sure that video file is available with relative path media\db.mp4?  as it is available in right hand side HTML. from the project explorer i can see that there is no media folder its in the root. so it should be db.mp4 instead of media\db.mp4

Comment: Yea you are right. The Path was incorrect. It is working now. Thank you.

Comment: i have posted the answer in edit part, Please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the mime type of the video in the `<source>` tag.

```
<source src="vid.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
```

Comment: I found out what was doing on. The path was wrong. The default path was already a1. So when I put a1/db.mp4 the full path turned into a1/a1/db.mp4